# How to convert pid_t to string

Tags: c, pid

So, I need to strcat pid to some string. 
I have this

```
strcat (str,(char*)getpid());
```

but this doesn't work.

----edit----

ok i understand the downvotes. i was too quick to post a question. and didnt realize pid returns an int and i can't cast an int to char*

itoa doesnt work because it is not standart c.

this is how i did it.

```
char pid[10];
snprintf(pid, 10,"%d",(int)getpid());
strcat (str, pid);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `strcat` to build a string, consider using the much more flexible (and efficient!) `sprintf`/`snprintf` function instead:

```
char *end = str;
end += sprintf(end, "%s ", "hello!");
end += sprintf(end, "%ld", (long)getpid());
if(bar)
    end += sprintf(end, "%x", 0xf00d);
```

Observe that `sprintf` returns the number of characters written, so you can build a string without succumbing to [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm). If you want to ensure that you don't overrun a buffer of fixed size, `snprintf` will do this for you (`strcat` will just blindly concatenate, and there is no standard way to avoid that).

Note that the [`pid_t` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/sys/types.h.html) guarantees that there are "one or more programming environments in which the [width] of `pid_t`... is no greater than the width of type `long`". Therefore, casting `pid_t` to `long` is safe as long as `getconf` says so.

Comment: This has the same problem as Ed Heal's answer.

Comment: Indeed. Thankyou for helping me to eliminate undefined behaviour :)

Answer (score 1):

I see several references that mention casting to long, and then using the `%ld` format specifier of sprintf: `sprintf(str + strlen(str), "%ld", (long) getpid());`

Comment: This is only guaranteed by the standard to work if the current programming environment is in the list returned by `getconf POSIX_V6_WIDTH_RESTRICTED_ENVS`. Otherwise, this too is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @nneonneo: All implementations shall support one or more environments where the widths of the following types are no greater than the width of type long:

blksize_t, cc_t, mode_t, nfds_t, pid_t, ptrdiff_t, size_t, speed_t, ssize_t, suseconds_t, tcflag_t, useconds_t, wchar_t, wint_t

Comment: Yeah, and the implementation can support environments in which that isn't true, and you have to check if your environment is of that form, or put in the compiler flags to make it so.

Comment: @nneonneo: If you're suggesting that this is UB on a non-POSIX system, then so be it. I'm suggesting that the system is relatively POSIX compliant.

Comment: @nneonneo What are your justifications that *nobody does in practice*? Have you studied every makefile in existence?

Comment: Actually, a fully POSIX compliant system may have multiple programming environments. Only one of these needs to support `sizeof(pid_t) <= sizeof(long)` in order to be POSIX-compliant. Other environments may support basically anything. (The other environments must still hew to basic POSIX compatibility -- they can't just go off the rails and e.g. act like Windows).

Comment: I've seen enough autoconf to know that people usually just rely on autoconf to figure out the width of `pid_t` for them ;)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue - What happens if `str` is `char s; char *str = &s; s = 0;` - We can all play this game

Comment: @EdHeal: I know the definition of *string* and *pointer to string*. You seem to have gone off topic. Please don't do that.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue - You are using `sprintf` into memory not allocated - i.e. back to undefined behaviour - one thing that you think that we should avoid.